# Configure RequestMappingHandlerAdapter in java based configuration respective to messageconverter

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am developing RestFul web service and I am beginner, I want to configure `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` in my java based configuration respective to the below xml based configuration.

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

And my java based configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mzk.mascot")
public class DispatcherServletConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        return httpMessageConverter;
    }



@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());

    }
  }
```

As per XML i need a equivalent configuration of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`

Comment: Implement `configureMessageConverters`.

Comment: already implemented, see my edits

Comment: That's all you should need. Assuming there's nothing else in your code you aren't showing us, those get added to the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` returned for `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: they by default added to RequestMappingHandlerAdapter but how???

Comment: To process `@EnableWebMvc`, Spring MVC creates a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` that ends up calling your class' `configureMessageConverters` with its list of converters.

Comment: thanks, can you provide me some more internal working detailed regarding this, so it will be beneficial for every viewer.